# Help choosing a better Chinese name

Tags: mandarin, names, surnames

Recently, someone helped me come up with a Chinese name for myself, and after some discussion, the surname 高 and given names 偉恩, 大恩 and 太恩 were recommended.

The first (偉恩) I liked but found that it was commonly used as a transliteration of the English name Wayne, which can be inconvenient.  Out of the latter two, I ended up choosing 大恩, mainly because I liked the meaning behind it. (I'm a Christian, and I really liked having a name that references my faith and such.)

After using the name for a bit, I've found that I'm not a fan of how it sounds so much when spoken. After trying out 太恩 for a bit, I've found that it's not my favourite either.

So I was wondering if any of you here had any suggestions for names / variations of the above names that you'd recommend for me?  Like 大恩, I'd like it if it references my beliefs / the Bible in some way.  Family name wise I'm fine with 高 (as well as 李, which I like), though other suggestions are fine!

In the end though I'd like a name that's relatively common. In the past I've used names that (I found out later) weren't overly common, which caused a few interesting moments when people saw my name.  So I'd like to avoid that if possible!

A name that also works in Cantonese as well as Mandarin would be cool as well, if possible!

Thank you so much in advance!

*(I'm not sure if this is the best place to ask for Chinese name help, but since I had a previous post specifically about the name 大恩 and such, I felt this is a good place to ask at least.)*

Answer (score 1):

Sounds good.

I have no more suggestions on the surname since you can pick whatever you want while there's no choice for a native Chinese lol.

As for the given name, there's no difference between 太 and 大 semantically. The similarity can also be seen orthologically. For example, the word 太后(empress dowager) is made up with the morpheme 太(big, giant, great, equivalent with 大) and the morpheme 后(empress consort). Even though, 太恩 sounds a little strange since the word 太 is rarely used in a name as far as I know.

The usage of 大 in a given name, in my opinion, is somewhat obsolete in China, which can be commonly found in names of people born in the 1960s or so. 偉恩, however, is a good name which is neither rarely nor commonly used and the conventional translation to Wayne is 韋恩 but not 偉恩.

I vote for 高偉恩 among the given chocies.

Answer (score 1):

大恩 and 太恩, both sound like Korean names(after translating).

I did some google search, found your name
Matthew means "gift of god",

if you like the "gift of god", not sure do you like 高天赠 ?

Comment: 高天赠 is pretty good, I like the meaning as it's similar to Matthew.    Not sure which one I'll go with in the end (偉恩, 天赠, or another one), I guess I'll have to think about it more.   Thank you so much for the suggestion!